# Real closure is the smallest real-closed field extension

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, ordered-fields

Let $F$ be an ordered field, $R/F$ a real closure and $R'$ an arbitrary real-closed field extension of $F$. Need there be an (ordered) $F$-homomorphism $R\to R'$? Does this follow from the essential uniqueness of the real closure?

Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Yes, this is almost immediate from the uniqueness of the real closure.  Let $R'_0$ be the subfield of $R'$ consisting of the elements that are algebraic over $F$.  Then $R'_0$ is also real-closed (how you prove this depends on how you define "real-closed"; for many definitions it is trivial), and so it is a real closure of $F$.  Thus there is an isomorphism $R\to R'_0$ over $F$.

(Alternatively, this should follow immediately from the *proof* that real closures are unique.  I don't know what proof of that fact you have seen, but every proof that I know of can be trivially modified to prove this statement instead.)

Comment: And that the order is defined algebraically so it is unique